# checking if a value is present in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to compare a string with an array to see if the string is present in the array and if so echo 'in array'. I keep only being able to have the echo work as I want with the very last entry in the array.

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    foreach($entries as $entry) {
        if($entry == $value) echo 'in array 1';
    }
    if (in_array($value, $entries)) {
        echo 'in array 2';
    }
    if(isset($entries[$value])) {
        echo 'in array 3';
    }
}
```

the echo for 'in array 1' and 'in array 2' work only on whatever the very last entry in the $entries array is, and the echo for 'in array 3' doesnt work at all.

Its probably something stupid but I am not seeing it...

edit:

here is some examples of the arrays

```
$entries =
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(14) "example text 1"
  [1]=>
  string(14) "example text 2"
  [2]=>
  string(14) "example text 3"
  [3]=>
  string(14) "example text 4"
  [4]=>
  string(14) "example text 5"
}

$array = 
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(14) "example text 1"
  [1]=>
  string(14) "example text 2"
  [2]=>
  string(14) "example text 3"
  [3]=>
  string(14) "example text 7"
  [4]=>
  string(14) "example text 8"
}
```

so now when I do

```
foreach($array as $key => $value)
```

$value should have the values from my $array and I need to compare each one of those values to see if they are present in my $entries array. If so id like to echo 'in array'

edit 2:

if it makes a difference my $entries array is being created by file() since the information is coming from a log. Everytime a new file is added, it is logged, then i want to compare incoming files to the log, determine if they have been added already, and if not, add them.

Comment: I'm confused, you say you're comparing a string with an array, but it looks like you're comparing an array with an array.. can you provide some sample data in all these arrays/strings and what you are getting and what you are expecting?

Comment: well $value is a string thats stored in an array, im looping through $array to get each $value, then comparing $value to each value in $entries ($entry)

Comment: so each character of your string is in $value? like 'cat' is `array('c', 'a', 't');` ? or do you mean each word from a string is in $value? like 'cat sat on the mat' is `array('cat', 'sat', 'on', 'the', 'mat');` ? and what is in $entries?

Comment: i added examples of my arrays, but the value of my array is a string, my array itself doesnt string together to create a word/sentence

Comment: When I try it, the first two work as expected: http://codepad.org/80zPyHqD

Comment: @Tom Smilack thank you i will look again at my code as a whole and see if the error lies elsewhere

Comment: Your example is two arrays of strings, your fist line 'compare a string' is actually incorrect description of your problem. To find what is in common between two arrays use `array_intersect($one, $two)`, if you just need to know if there are any common values, you can forloop over one array with in_array on the other, like you have done - your code for that should work, a bit less efficient way would be `count(array_intersect($one, $two))`

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems to just check what is in common in two arrays, and does it three different ways. The reason one will work over another depends on the data. The there comparators `==`, `in_array` and `isset` work differently. Really need to see your array structure / sample data to comment further.

However, what you're currently doing, finding common elements of two arrays, can easily be done with `array_diff()` or `array_intersect()`

Your very first line -

> I am trying to compare a string with an array to see if the string is
>   present in the array and if so echo 'in array'.

can just be achieved with just one call to `in_array`, like `in_array('cat', array('cat', 'dog', 'mouse'));`

Comment: the 3 different ways were for testing and i couldnt get any of my ways to work.

Answer (score 1):

`$value` is not a key.

Value is a "value".

if you **really** wanted to do what you are doing you could do:

```
if(isset(array_flip($entries)[$value])) {
    echo 'in array 3';
}
```

But it might not work if you have several elements with the same value.

[See DOCs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php)

Comment: so how come my first 2 variations work only on the last entry?